# Como puedo llamar a los validators en los rule del Form.item en antd solo cuando el value.length en mayor a 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design

Hola estoy usando los form de antd y tengo un inconveniente con el validator de las rules. Lo que pasa es que el comportamiento no es el deseado. Cuando el input esta vacío y le doy al boton enviar del form me salen todas las validaciones del validator y solo deseo que se lanze el message del required.

imagen del comportamiendo no deseado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

imagen del comportamiento deseado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la regla del form:

```
const rules = [
{ required: true, message: 'Password is required.' },
{
  validator: (_, value) =>
    value && value.length >= 8
      ? Promise.resolve()
      : Promise.reject(new Error('Password must be at least 8 characters')),
},
{
  validator: (_, value) =>
    value && value.match(/\d+/g)
      ? Promise.resolve()
      : Promise.reject(new Error('Password must have one number')),
}, 
 ];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola pude resolver el problema con este algoritmo:

```
              {
              validator: (rule, value, callback) => {
                try {
                  console.log('EL value', value);
                  if (value && !value.match(/\d+/g)) {
                    throw new Error('Password must have one number');
                  } else {
                    callback();
                  }
                } catch (err) {
                  callback(err);
                }
              },
            },
            {
              validator: (rule, value, callback) => {
                try {
                  console.log('EL value', value);
                  if (value && value.length < 8) {
                    throw new Error(
                      'Password must be at least 8 characters'
                    );
                  } else {
                    callback();
                  }
                } catch (err) {
                  callback(err);
                }
              },
            },
```